# Typo in declared prop type: boolean (Eslint)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-proptypes

I am doing everything correctly but for some reason, Eslint is flagging the boolean keyword as invalid, even calling it a typo.
Should I find a way to silence it, or is there a fix for this error?
I am coding in Strict mode so it is failing

```
auth: PropTypes.shape({
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.boolean,
    loading: PropTypes.func,
  }).isRequired,
``
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it seems the boolean keyword is obsolete; according to the Airbnb, styles guide for React.

simply change it to this and it would work;

```
auth: PropTypes.shape({
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
    loading: PropTypes.func,
  }).isRequired,
```

That should be accepted.

Comment: Why you put the same code of the question to answer?